# How can I add a custom button to my product single page in Jupiter theme?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I need to add a custom button to my shop single pages while using Jupiter WordPress theme and its Shop Customizer. Usually, I do it with a child theme and override the WooCommerce folder inside it, but since they have their own layout files, I can not do it like this.

Is there any way I add a custom button below the "Add to Cart" button with the hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, at first you need enable your child theme, then add this code into jupiter-child/functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
  global $product;
  echo '<div class="mk-button-container _ relative custom_shop_button block text-center ">
<a href="#LINK_TO_WHAT_YOU_WANT" target="_self" class="mk-button js-smooth-scroll mk-button--dimension-three mk-button--size-medium mk-button--corner-pointed text-color-light _ relative text-center font-weight-700 no-backface letter-spacing-1 inline"><span class="mk-button--text">Link Text</span></a>
</div>';
}
```

The global **$product variable** let you fetch the product details. For more info, check this out: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/class-reference/

Then add this CSS in Custom CSS section in Jupiter Theme Options:

```
.custom_shop_button .mk-button, .custom_shop_button .mk-button:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #b31913;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.custom_shop_button .mk-button {
    background-color: #e01f18;
    color: #fff!important;
}
.custom_shop_button .mk-button {
    background-color: #e01f18;
}
.custom_shop_button .mk-button {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}



@media screen and (min-width: 768px )
{
    .custom_shop_button {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    clear: both !important;
    margin-top: 57px;
}

.woocommerce div.product form.cart, .woocommerce-page div.product form.cart {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px )
{
    .custom_shop_button {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both !important;
    text-align: left;
}

.woocommerce div.product form.cart, .woocommerce-page div.product form.cart {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Will try that. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!